# Destroy a JPopupMenu in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I'm using a JPopupMenu displayed when I do a right click on certain components in my GUI.

Now I have to destroy the popup menu displayed in this 2 situation:

1. The user click on a menu entry displayed into the popup (do the related action and close the popup)
2. The user click somewhere else on the screen(close the popup without do anything)

I solved this problem storing into an ArrayList the current visible popups and I manually set them to be invisible when one of the 2 previous situation occured.

So, i would like to know 2 things:

1. Is there any cleaner way of doing that without manually taking the reference of all active popups? (perhaps any Swing feature do accomplish that? )
2. Is just enough to set a popup unvisible having no more references to that object, in order to free its allocated memory? Or have I to use a method like dispose ? (there isn't a dispose method defined in JPopupMenu)

It is a bit difficult to show my actual code, because it's a bit complex. Anyway it does the following:

```
public EditorPopupMenu getPopupMenu() {
    this.popupMenu = new EditorPopupMenu();

    EditorMenuItem copy = GuiConcreteFactory.getInstance().createMenuItem(Gui.getInstance().copyItemAction);
    EditorMenuItem cut = GuiConcreteFactory.getInstance().createMenuItem(Gui.getInstance().cutItemAction);
    EditorMenuItem paste = GuiConcreteFactory.getInstance().createMenuItem(Gui.getInstance().pasteItemAction);

    this.popupMenu.add(copy);
    this.popupMenu.add(cut);
    this.popupMenu.add(paste);

    this.popupMenu.addSeparator();

    EditorMenuItem settings = GuiConcreteFactory.getInstance().createMenuItem(
                                                new ApplicationShowDialogAction("settings",null, 
                                                        new EditorAreaDialog (this)) );
    this.popupMenu.add(settings);
    return popupMenu;
}
```

Where EditorPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu. Previous code is called by a MouseListener when a click happend on a particular object and the specified object constructs its popup menu and returns it.

From inside the MouseListener:

```
if (me.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK){
                // //System.out.println("ResizableMouseAdapter: BUTTON_3_MASK");


                 EditorPopupMenu popupMenu = sourceComp.getType().getPopupMenu();
                 if ( popupMenu!= null){
                     //System.out.println("COMPONENT HAS A POPUP MENU");
                     popupMenu.setLocation( sourceComp.getLocationOnScreen().x + me.getX(),
                                            sourceComp.getLocationOnScreen().y + me.getY());
                     popupMenu.setVisible(true);
                     Gui.getInstance().addActivePopup(popupMenu);
                 }

             }
```

This is all. With this code my JPopupMenu doesn't dissapear properly.

Comment: I might be a bit thick this morning, but isn't that behavior exactly what Swing does by default?  I've used JPopupMenu a lot before and have never had to manually hide one.

Comment: @I82Much: It seems not. I thought that what i described was a default behavior too, but it isn't.

Comment: Could you provide some code? I just tested it and what you describe is what actually happens (for me)

Comment: @I82Much @Tedil: i edited my post. Check it and thanks for your attention

Comment: _The user click somewhere else on the screen(close the popup without do anything)_ : why do you want this behavior?

Comment: @noob: because suppose the user click and show a popup but he doesn't want to go ahead in choosing one of the action showed in the popup, popup it self must be closed. The easiest way should be click somewhere else in the screen.

Comment: @Overbose: Right, sorry...I was thinking about `JDialog`. But like camickr said, `this is the default behavior`.

Comment: @ 0verbose I think that link posted by camickr shows method "public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {", inside this method you can set anything for JPopupMenu (before popup#maybeShowPopup(e);)

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for an explanation and working example.

Comment: it seems should be the default  behavior. You are right. Anyway it doesn't work for me. I posted some code. Have you got any idea?

Comment: @Overbose, "some code" does not help. We can't tell the context of how/where your code is used. I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial which contains a working example. Learn from the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `show` method instead of the `setVisible` method.